# How to understand this usage of typedef?

Tags: c, msdn

Here's the code:

```
typedef char FlagType;

int main()
{
}

int myproc( int )
{
    int FlagType;
}
```

copied from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/typedef-declarations?view=msvc-160

In my understanding, 'typedef char FlagType' makes 'char a' and 'FlagType a' no difference. But I can't understand the 'int FlagType'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read a few lines above, they're describing how the namespaces are separated.

This example shows a `typedef` of type `char` named `FlagType` and a variable in `myproc()` of type `int` named `FlagType`.

This is stupid, and nobody should do it, but it is legal from a language parsing standpoint.

I had the same "WTF‽" reaction when I first learned of nested [anonymous structures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-38-anonymous-union-and-structure/).

Comment: That page follows a pretty much messed up concept: They first tell you how to confuse yourself, then how to do it properly...

Comment: Yes, though a common technique in CS education, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

The code demonstrates a pathological example. Not a standard or recommended use case.

It is shown to explain what happens when a local variable has the same name as a typedef name.

> Typedef names share the name space with ordinary identifiers (see Name
> Spaces for more information). Therefore, a program can have a typedef
> name and a local-scope identifier by the same name.

Comment: So much more poetic than my response. :)